# Почему Icecast2 не хочет отдавать поток через https?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, streaming, icecast

Вопрос к знатокам Icecast'а.
На сервере с Ubuntu 14.04 запущен Icecast2 версии 2.4.1 с поддержкой OpenSSL.
Также на этом сервере живет сайт радио, настроенный строго на HTTPS.
На сайт требуется вставить HTML5-плеер, который будет забирать поток также через SSL (иначе - смешанное содержимое). 
У сайта покупной сертификат, в Icecast - самоподписанный.
Конфиг Icecast'а:

```
<icecast>
<location>****</location>
<admin>admin@*************</admin>
<limits>
    <clients>1000</clients>
    <sources>2</sources>
    <threadpool>5</threadpool>
    <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
    <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
    <burst-on-connect>0</burst-on-connect>
    <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
</limits>
<authentication>
    <source-password>*****</source-password>
    <relay-password>*****</relay-password>
    <admin-user>*****</admin-user>
    <admin-password>*****</admin-password>
</authentication>
<hostname>************</hostname> 
<listen-socket>
    <port>8000</port>
    <ssl>1</ssl>
</listen-socket>
<mount>
    <mount-name>/stream</mount-name>
    <charset>utf-8</charset>
</mount>
<mount> 
    <mount-name>/ogg</mount-name>
    <charset>utf-8</charset>
</mount>
<fileserve>1</fileserve>
<paths>
    <basedir>/usr/share/icecast2</basedir>
    <logdir>/var/log/icecast2</logdir>
    <webroot>/usr/share/icecast2/web</webroot>
    <adminroot>/usr/share/icecast2/admin</adminroot>
    <alias source="/" dest="/status.xsl"/>
<ssl-certificate>/etc/icecast2/icecast2.pem</ssl-certificate>
</paths>
<logging>
    <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
    <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
    <loglevel>4</loglevel>
</logging>
<security>
    <chroot>0</chroot>
    <changeowner>
        <user>icecast2</user>
        <group>icecast</group>
    </changeowner>
</security>
</icecast>
```

Сертификат для Icecast (/etc/icecast2/icecast2.pem) сгенерирован при помощи:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout icecast2.pem -out icecast2.pem
```

Я ожидаю получить на выходе поток по адресам `https://domain.name:8000/stream` и `https://domain.name:8000/ogg` для вставки в плеер через тег audio, но в ответ - тишина.
При этом по адресам с простым http все работает отлично.
Не могу никак понять в чем же ошибка.

**UPD.** Попробовал поставить сертификат от самого домена - результат тот же.

Comment: "самоподписанный" - так, может, в этом и дело? Ссылку на радио в отдельной вкладке открывать пробовали? Браузер ошибку сертификата случайно не пишет? И нельзя ли прицепить icecast'у сертификат этого самого сайта?

Comment: Я пробовал прикрепить сертификат самого сайта (там требуется объединенный (на сайт  и на CA) - результат тоже самый. Браузеры ошибок не пишут. Если скормить ссылку обычному плееру типа AIMP - тоже не работает.

Comment: а что в лог-файлах `/var/log/icecast2/error.log` и `/var/log/icecast2/access.log` встречается про ssl?

Comment: В логах только упоминание о том, что сертификат /etc/icecast2/icecast2.pem успешно найден. В access.log есть интересная строка (Firefox пытался загрузить поток): "HEAD /stream HTTP/1.1" 400 304

Comment: попробуйте продублировать секцию listen-socket с разными портами. одну с ssl, другую — без.

Comment: @alexander barakin я уже попробовал такой вариант. К сожалению, не взлетело...

Comment: EROR connection/connection_setup_sockets Could not create listener socket on port 8000. Пробовал отдельно на порту 8001, тоже не пошло...

Answer (score -1):

Использовал *Nginx*, который проксирует запросы к *Icecast* на `127.0.0.0.1:8000`.
*Icecast* БЕЗ сертификата. И поэтому, все запросы идут через HTTPS.